# Console.Terminate event on a specific command

Tags: php, symfony, events, console

I just discovered that it exists a ConsoleEvents::TEMINATE event in Symfony.
I want to use it to execute some additional process after the command execution (and not delaying the command).

But the fact is that i want to execute some process when a specific command is finish, not for all the commands (because i think that consoleevent.terminate is fired for all the commands.

I really don't know how to do that.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can access instance of the command from `ConsoleTerminateEvent`

It's almost copy paste from documentation of Console component. with full symfony registering listener looks a little different but you should get the idea.

```
$dispatcher->addListener(
    ConsoleEvents::TERMINATE,
    function(ConsoleTerminateEvent $event) {
        $command = $event->getCommand();

        // if it's not the command you want
        if (!$command instanceof YourDesiredCommand) {
            return;
        }

        // put your logic here
    }
);
```